# Trying to play Audio with UILocalNotification

Tags: uilocalnotification

My application shows a `LocalNotification` when it is in background state. I want to play a sound when `LocalNotification` is fired. Apparently I can use the `LocalNotification`.Soundname property to mention the file name which is in the app bundle. What is want is to play a sound from documents directory,because I recorded sounds when the app is in active state and it is saved in documents directory. I am using the `AVAudioPlayer` object to play it. Its working fine in the simulator, but it is not working on the device. Here is the code how I am doing it.

```
if([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground)
                        {
                            UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
                            if (localNotif == nil)
                                return;
                            localNotif.fireDate = [NSDate date];
                            localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

                            // Notification details
                            localNotif.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You Got %d Email(s) From %@",newMailsFrom[i],[(ModelNameEmail *)[[MailModel sharedMailModel].EmailAlertArray objectAtIndex:i] Name]];
                            // Set the action button
                            localNotif.alertAction = @"View";

                            localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
                            localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = +1;

                            // Specify custom data for the notification
                            NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"someValue" forKey:@"someKey"];
                            localNotif.userInfo = infoDict;


                            //playing the sound


                            NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                            NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];

                            NSString *filename = [(ModelNameEmail *)[[MailModel sharedMailModel].EmailAlertArray objectAtIndex:0] Name];
                            NSString *filename1 = [filename stringByAppendingFormat:@".wav"];
                            NSString *filepath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename1];
                            NSLog(@"sound file path is %@",filepath);

                            //NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/welcome.wav", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

                            NSURL *url =[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];

                            NSError *error;
                            audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
                            [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];

                            audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;

                            [audioPlayer play];

                            //  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
                            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotif];
                            [localNotif release];


                        `
```